# nuxt 3 webpack with vutify Treeshaking

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, nuxtjs3

I use nuxt 3 with webpack and i want to do treeshaking for vuetify
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/treeshaking/#treeshaking

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
builder: 'webpack',

hooks: {

    webpack: {

        config(configs) {
            plugins: [
                new VueLoaderPlugin(),
                new VuetifyPlugin(),
            ]


        }
    }

},
}
```

My plugiun vutify:
import   'vuetify/styles'

```
export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
    const vuetify = createVuetify({
        ssr: true,
        theme: {
            dark: true, // From 2.0 You have to select the theme dark or light here
        },

    })



    nuxtApp.vueApp.use(vuetify)
})
```

This is not working. How i can add treeshaking?